# Is "every non-empty set is injective" equivalent to AC?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is well known that "every surjection has a section" is an equivalent form of the axiom of choice (in fact, for me it is *the* most natural formulation of the axiom of choice). In detail, the statement is that for any map $f:X\to Y$ such that for every $y\in Y$ there is an $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$ there is a map $s:Y\to X$ with $f(s(y))=y$ for every $y\in Y$.

Consider the statement "every injection with non-empty domain has a retraction". In detail, for any map $f:X\to Y$ such that $X$ is not empty and $f(x)=f(x')$ implies $x=x'$ for any $x,x'\in X$, there is a map $r:Y\to X$ with $r(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in X$.

Is this statement also equivalent to the axiom of choice? If not, is it weaker or stronger? What are some "well-established" set-theoretic principles equivalent to it?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903645/existence-of-a-set-function-axiom-of-choice

Answer (score 2):

No. Fix a point $x'\in X$ and define$$\begin{array}{rccc}r\colon&Y&\longrightarrow&X\\&y&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if $y=f(x)$ for some }x\in X\\x'&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you! I now think it is probably equivalent to excluded middle or something like that...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: When the standard proof (full classical logic, with choice, with everything) is four lines, **check the four lines** and see where the axiom of choice might have been involved. It's a much shorter process than even writing the question. In fact, I am pretty sure that answering your question is shorter than writing *this* comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are right - almost :D I am mostly interested in the last part. From the answer I got impression that it is probably equivalent to excluded middle

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer shows proving your statement does not require the axiom of choice. Your statement, however, implies the weak excluded middle. We will work over CZF and take the terminology $0=\{\}$ and $1=\{0\}$.

Let $\phi$ be a $\Delta_0$-formula. Take $a = \{0\mid \phi\}$ and consider the inclusion map $i:\{0,1\}\to \{0,a,1\}$. Assume that $i$ has a corresponding retraction $r:\{0,a,1\}\to \{0,1\}$, then $r(a)=0$ or $r(a)=1$.

Now assume that $r(a)=0$ and $\phi$. The combination of them implies $r(1)=0$. However $r(1) = r(i(1)) = 1$, a contradiction. Hence $r(a)=0$ implies $\lnot\phi$. Similarly we can prove $r(a)=1$ implies $\lnot\lnot\phi$. In summary, we have $\lnot\phi\lor\lnot\lnot\phi$.

As the proof suggests, your statement implies weak excluded middle for any formulas if we assume the full separation.

Comment: That's nice! Is it clear that the "actual" (strong) excluded middle cannot be similarly implied?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I have tried, but I still have no idea on this.

Comment: Let $a := \{x \in 2 | (x = 0) \vee (x = 1 \wedge \phi)\}$ and let $i$ be the inclusion $a \subseteq 2$. Let $r : 2 \to a$ be a retraction. If $r(1) = 0$ then $\phi$ is false. Hence if $\neg \neg \phi$ holds then $r(1) \neq 0$, and so $r(1) = 1$, implying $\phi$. We have shown $\neg \neg \phi \Rightarrow \phi$, which is double negation elimination and equivalent to excluded middle.

Comment: @aws Nice proof!